# How to replace specific words in multiple wordpress post titles at once?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

There are some outdated plugins. But those are not seem to be useful and not actually working.

There are 2000 post titles and I want to bulk edit/replace specific word from them. How can I do this by using mysql command?

Like this : Changing `Sloppy` to `Ronn` in 2000 wordpress post titles at once. How can I do that?

Comment: Originally it was written by Frank Bueltge, awesome developer, nowadays his company is behind it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/ It does the job for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/cm-on-demand-search-and-replace/

otherwise try running this command:

```
UPDATE table_name 
   SET field_name = replace(field_name, 'string_to_change', 'new_string')
```

Comment: with that command, it will only change the titles of posts, right? Because I only want to replace some words in 2000 titles.

Comment: yes. You have to replace table_name with your table's name and field_name with the field name used for the title. I think it is "post_title " or something similar.

Comment: Yes it worked. Can you also give the command for post texts? I also want to change some texts inside of posts and moreover urls. Will be appreciated.